# How to get text from span class using Selenium ChromeDriver

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I looked simillar questions at stackoverflow and didn't find anything that can help me.

I have following html code:

```
<span class="help-block ng-scope" translate="">Company</span>
```

How can i find this element (Java)? I tried following variants:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".help-block.ng-scope"))

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, "Company")]"))
```

I even tried to just copy xpath from browser console in two ways:

First:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="ngCloudike"]/body/div[6]/div/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div[6]/span"))
```

Second:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div[6]/span"))
```

Also i tried to find By.ClassName, but i can't do this, because there are some spaces. So, how can i find element like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below expression:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Company']"))
```

If you get `NoSuchElementException` with this code, try to add some time to wait until element present and visible:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='Company']"))
```

If you get `NoSuchElementException` even with `ExplicitWait`, target element might be located inside an `iframe`. To handle element inside an `iframe`:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("iframeNameOrId");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Company']"));
```

Comment: Still NoSuchElementException

Comment: U|sing `ExplicitWait` (http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) is much better than sleeps- it allow to save time. If my answer help you to resolve problem, please mark it as `Accepted`. Thanks